# Validate Input of Bootstrap jQuery Modal Dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do you validate Input control of a Bootstrap jQuery modal dialog?
The examples of modal dialogs are in this link http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Examples of Boostrap Modal have this type of Input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-email">
```

How do I validate the Input "recipient-email" as required field and a valid email address?

Answer (score 0):

This what you looking for, whole library is available in github

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/modal/

Comment: If this works fine please accept or reject, somebody following will be helped by doing so

Answer (score 0):

In modal put in content a form and validate when user submit. Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6tjogqr/3/)

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-email" />
</form>
```

Comment: Diego, thank you for the suggestion. However I cannot see anything in the fiddle.